# Showing $\langle a,b\mid abab^{-1}\rangle$ and $ \langle c,d \mid c^2d^2\rangle$ are isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

I computed the fundamental group of the Klein bottle in two different ways and obtained two seemingly different answers:
$$
\langle a,b \mid abab^{-1}\rangle
$$
and
$$
\langle c,d \mid c^2d^2\rangle.
$$
I then tried to show that these two groups are in fact the same:
\begin{align*}
\langle a,b \mid abab^{-1}\rangle
=\langle ab,b^{-1} \mid abab^{-1}\rangle
&=\langle ab,b^{-1} \mid (ab)(ab)b^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle\\
&=\langle c,d \mid c^2d^2\rangle
\end{align*}
Is my method for doing so valid?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The second step doesn't really make sense as a presentation, but if you skip it then everything is fine. It might be clearest that these groups are isomorphic if you added the intermediate group $$\langle a,b,c,d| abab^{-1},ab=c,d=b^{-1},c^2d^2\rangle$$
which admits obvious maps from each of the two desired groups which one readily proves to be surjective (since $c$ and $d$ are in the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$) and injective (since the first and last relations are each implied by the other three.)